# Open a .doc file stored in SQL Server image column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload

I have many *.doc* files stored in a SQL Server 2008 `IMAGE` column. I don't know how that datatype still exists in 2008, but I clearly can see it. The software database is old, and database server had to be upgraded to 2008. Anyway - somehow - the software still functions very well.

Last months my company decided to go for web solution, but with keeping all the data intact. I've developed whole system for that, and everything goes very good - INSTEAD OF FILES... Anytime I try to "download" bytes from the SQL `IMAGE` column, I get the file, but it's corrupted (at least I'm getting a lot of stupid chars in MS Word). But when I insert the new file (storing it in `IMAGE` col), and then download it, everything is going well.

Does anybody in this world have an idea what can be wrong with it?

Here is the link to one of corrupted files in DB:
https://hotfile.com/dl/226441204/438414c/testFile.doc.html

Comment: If new records work fine, then either existing records are corrupted or existing records aren't stored like you think.

Comment: when you upgraded the server did you change the Collation from whatever it was originally?

Comment: Very good suggestion. This will be the first thing I will try. Tomorrow morning I will be back here to report...

Answer (score 0):

According to your description something went wrong while upgrading the database server to 2008.

Comment: Huh, any possible know solution for that? I have DB backup, so how can I migrate it successfully?

Comment: I suggest you ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ specially what happends while upgrading with image columns. alternatively you can write a small program which reads the files from an old database version and write it to the one after the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in those directions. As soon as I try the suggestions, I am getting back to report... Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

After days of investigation, I finally came to solution. As the database was made by the 3rd party, I had to know their filesave logic in order to make it work. Apparently, collations and other thing were too easy to solve the issue. Then I came up to JetBrains DotPeek, .NET decompiler that is awesome. It had everything I need for determining the exact saving flow. I've found that files were saved with password protected stream. It was easy to find the password, as now I had all the code open. Dotfuscating slightly hardened my research, but everything is just fine now... Finally!!! Thanks to everyone who tried to help me on my road to solution....